# SNMP Network traffic difference between 32-bit and 64-bit Counter

Tags: networking, switch-statement, monitoring, snmp, zabbix

I try to monitor some Cisco 2960x Switch devices and I know there are the SNMP OID's ifInOctets (32-bit Counter) and ifHCinOctets (64-bit Counter). Can someone explain me whats the difference between those Counters and which one I should use for a GigabitEthernet Interface?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

64-bit counters are used for high capacity interfaces where 32-bit counters do not provide enough capacity and wrap too fast.

As the speed of network media increases, the minimum time in which a 32-bit counter wraps decreases.

For example, a 10 Mbps stream of back-to-back, full-size packets causes ifInOctets to wrap in just over 57 minutes. At 100 Mbps, the minimum wrap time is 5.7 minutes, and at 1 Gbps, the minimum is 34 seconds.

For interfaces that operate at 20,000,000 (20 million) bits per second or less, you must use 32-bit byte and packet counters. For interfaces that operate faster than 20 million bits per second, and slower than 650,000,000 bits per second, you must use 32-bit packet counters and 64-bit octet counters. For interfaces that operate at 650,000,000 bits/second or faster, 64-bit packet and octet counters must be used.

You can check the following [link](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/ip/simple-network-management-protocol-snmp/26007-faq-snmpcounter.html) for detailed explanation on SNMP counters.